# How to light megastructures in Minecraft without torch orglowstone spam?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-worldedit

I am building a very large underground airbase/bunker, and am having lighting troubles. Torches would look wildly out of place in a modern build, and even using glowstone doesn't seem to be having much of an effect, as the light diminishes a set distance from the block. Well, my hanger is 30 blocks tall. The roof is plenty lit, but the floor is not. [image: lit hanger]

This is with a Night Vision potion active.
[image: dark hanger]
This is without.

I'm running Worldedit (only way I can build something this big without taking a year) on 1.14.4, so any mods that work with that would be fine.
I have used Little Tiles and Chisels and Bits on another world in 1.12.2 to fill walls with glowstone for lighting, but I keep getting a glitch on there that makes random sections of the tiles disappear until I place a block next to them. If someone has a solution for that, I would use Little Tiles. Does Little Tiles for 1.14.4 have the same glitch, by the way?

Comment: My suggestion was going to be Chisels and Bits... Another option might be to use Immersive Engineering. It has some floodlamps which, besides fitting in well with the aesthetic, would light the place quite nicely.

Comment: @SaintWacko, can you run the floodlight without redstone in Creative?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way [lighting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Light) works in Minecraft. Any block emitting light that is *not marked as a sky light* has brightness at most 15 and falls off with each block of distance. Daylight / sky light is based on whether there is an unobstructed path of light to the sky (not including transparent blocks such as glass but including certain light-filtering blocks, see the wiki page for details). In vanilla there is no way around lighting huge caverns except for using daylight. With a modpack there may be "floodlights" that simulate the effect of daylight, or produce "beams" of full brightness light-emitting blocks.

Comment: Know of any good mods that work with Worldedit to do that sort of thing?

Comment: @Jazzyamx I have never used them myself. They are usually called floodlights in mods. There are floodlights in Immersive Engineering for one.